# Amazon Echo Account Linking - how to identify echo device when generating and saving token?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alex

I have a pre-existing web app with user accounts. I want to extend functionality with Amazon's echo.

When the user enables the skill in their Echo/Alexa dashboard, it will redirect them to the login page of my app with `Authorization URL https://foo.com/auth`.

I checked the incoming request that comes from `Authorization URL https://foo.com/auth` and there is no client id, user id, or user email on the request. It doesn't do me any good to generate a token and send it back to Amazon if I can't save that token on my webserver along with some kind of echo client device id.

From [Account linking implicit granting](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/link-an-alexa-user-with-a-user-in-your-system.html)

> 3 The user logs in using their normal credentials for your site.
>
> 4 Your service authenticates the user and then generates an access token 
>        that **uniquely identifies the user** in your system.

When amazon redirects users to my app to enter login credentials, how do I link their token I give back to them to their echo device for future requests?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't do that when the user enter his credentials, but after the linking is completed.

When the user launches your skill, you can identify him with the `context.System.user.userId`, the access token will be in  `context.System.user.accessToken` and the device in `context.System.device. deviceId`. The same `accessToken` can be used for multiple devices, and the `userId` will change if the user disables and re-enables your skill.

More info here: [Request and Response JSON Reference](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#system-object)